# Multiple log messages for missing translations in Angular-Translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I added the Missing Translation Handler Log on my AngularJS app to print on console any missing translation for a string. However, it seems that all the messages are printed on the console multiple times.

Here is the log:

```
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
Translation for deleteMyAccount doesn't exist angular.min.js:118
```

This is the AngularJS code on `app.module.js` file:

```
  translateConfig.$inject = ['$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider'];
    function translateConfig($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('header');
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('index');

        $translateProvider
            .useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
                urlTemplate: 'i18n/{lang}/{part}.json'
            })
        .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape')
        .preferredLanguage('en')
        .useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();
    };
```

How can a dig more and find the source of the problem?

AngularJS 1.5.8

Angular-Translate 2.13.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer adapted from my [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/5o3177/multiple_log_messages_for_missing_translations_in/dcgbg9l/).

You didn't share enough code. How do you use it? If you use the translate filter and don't use one-time bindings it will try to translate your strings on every digest and thus spam your console. It actually reveals a possible performance issue.

Do you use `translate="deleteMyAccount"` attribute directive or `{{ 'deleteMyAccount' | translate }}` filter? In the latter case Angular tries to translate the string every time anything changes in your application causing the error message to appear many times. To fix this you can turn it into a one-time binding by adding `::` after the starting bracket like so: `{{:: 'deleteMyAccount' | translate }}`. I think it is a good idea to always use one-time bindings if you do not expect your value to change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be telling you there's a 404 for the translation file 'i18n/en/deleteMyAccount.json', so make sure it exists.

As for the repeating error, what I've noticed is that once a partial file cannot be find for a route, it will try loading it again on every consecutive route change, causing multiple of these 404 logs.

Comment: deleteMyAccount is not a file but a string on the header.json file. As for the multiple lines, I am on the same route without changing states. And the message appears >5 times.

Comment: Right, sorry, misunderstood the question then. In that case, if the translation file is properly loaded, do any other translation strings defined in the JSON file work?

Comment: The strings that are in the file work. This one is missing but it should appear only once in the console log.